# PHP add text before and after an arrays elements

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

How can I wrap `<i>` `</i>` tags around `This is line one!`, `This is line two!`, `This is line three!` in `$thisStr` below, so the result is:

```
`<i>This is line one!</i>`
`<i>This is line two!</i>`
`<i>This is line three!</i>`
```

What I did only puts tags around the `::` parts. I cant get it to go back and forward and wrap tags.

`$thisStr = 'This is line one! :: This is line two! :: This is line three!';`

`echo preg_replace("/(::)/i", "<i>$1</i>", $thisStr);`

Comment: Where does `$thisStr` come from originally? If you can insert the `::` delimiters, you can also add the elements directly, right? On a side note, the `<i>` element is presentational markup and should be avoided in favor of `<em>`.

Comment: It comes from imploding an array. Like this `$lines[] = 'This is line one!';
$lines[] = 'This is line two!'; $thisStr = implode(' :: ',$lines);` But I need `$thisStr` the way it is, and then again with `<i>` tags

Comment: Umm, and what prevents you from just doing `$italicized = '<i>' . implode('</i><i>', $lines) . '</i>'`? Like I said, if you can insert `::`, you can insert anything else, too…

Answer (score 5):

This works great, but is not preg_replace:

```
$thisStr = 'This is line one! :: This is line two! :: This is line three!';

$result= "<i>".str_replace("::","</i><i>",$thisStr)."</i>";

echo $result;
```

Or, to match your exact example:

```
$thisStr = 'This is line one! :: This is line two! :: This is line three!';

$result= "'<i>".str_replace(" :: ","</i>'<br/>'<i>",$thisStr)."</i>'";

echo $result;

/*
'This is line one!'
'This is line two!'
'This is line three!'
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really really really need to use preg_replace this will work

```
$input_lines = "This is line one!
This is line two!
This is line three!";

$New_string = preg_replace("/This is line .*/", "<i>$0</i>", $input_lines);
```

The pattern looks for the string "this is line" and the .* means anything in any lenght.
Then the replace pattern is quite easy to understand I guess.

But i recommend the answer Verjas wrote.
There is no need for the extra complexty the preg_replace adds.

Comment: Here's what I was trying to do `preg_replace("/^(.*?)$/i", "<i>$1</i>", $array);`. This works, but I'm not sure how efficient it is. And, that text isn't static. It can be anything depending on the error messages generated.

Comment: preg_replace("/^(.*?)$/im", "<i>$0</i>", $input_lines);          http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/flQ  click on preg_replace

Comment: @Norman Never mind.. I didn't read what you wrote good enough. I believe they are equally efficient, Varjas and preg_replace. Use the one you find best and easiest to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$thisStr = 'This is line one! :: This is line two! :: This is line three!';
$lines = explode('::', $thisStr);
$result = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $result .= '<i>' . $line .'</i>';
}
echo htmlentities($result);
```

Hope this helps.